# Why does std::is_copy_constructible not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, type-traits, compile-time-constant

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    std::is_constructible_v<int&, const int&>; // false, as expected.
    std::is_copy_constructible_v<int&>; // true, NOT as expected!
}
```

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible):

> If T is an object or reference type and the variable definition T
>   obj(std::declval()...); is well-formed, provides the member
>   constant value equal to true. In all other cases, value is false.

`std::is_copy_constructible_v<int&>` should give the same result as `std::is_constructible_v<int&, const int&>` does; however, `clang 7.0` gives different results as shown above.

**Does this behavior conform to the C++ standards?**

Comment: On the other hand `using T = int&; static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<T, const T&>); // true` at least matches `is_copy_constructible_v` result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the reference for [is_copy_constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible) states is:

> If T is not a referenceable type (i.e., possibly cv-qualified void or a function type with a cv-qualifier-seq or a ref-qualifier), provides a member constant value equal to false. Otherwise, provides a member constant value equal to `std::is_constructible<T, const T&>::value`.

So, here `is_copy_constructible<T>::value` is the same as `std::is_constructible<T, const T&>::value`.

So in your case:

`std::is_constructible<int, const int&>::value` will be the same as `std::is_copy_constructible_v<int>`.

See [**`DEMO`**](https://godbolt.org/z/qR-Rc_)